# Pyomo assign value to constrain TypeError: Problem inserting

Tags: pyomo

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.time = Set(initialize = range(24*3))
model.option = Set(initialize = range(4))
model.time_soc = Var(model.time, bounds = (0.1,0.9), domain=PositiveReals)
model.time_option = Var(model.time, model.option, domain = Binary)
model.soc_param = Param(model.option, initialize={0:0, 1:-0.025, 2:-0.05, 3:0.125})
model.soc_ini = Param(initialize = 0.5)

def cons_time_opt(model, i):
    total_choice = sum(model.time_option[i,j] for j in model.option)
    return total_choice == 1

model.opt = Constraint(model.time, rule = cons_time_opt)

model.soc_con0 = Constraint(0.5 + model.time_option[0,j]*model.soc_param[j] == model.time_soc[0] for j in model.option)
```

I got the following error:

> ERROR: Constructing component 'soc_con0_index' from data=None failed:
>       TypeError: Problem inserting time_soc[0]  ==  0.5 into set soc_con0_index

Comment: I don't know what pyomo is but this looks like python syntax, and `model.soc_con0` looks like a typo. Need more of the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `soc_con0` constraint is meant to be an indexed constraint in which case you are missing a constraint rule. It should be:

```
def soc_con0_rule(model, j):
    return 0.5 + model.time_option[0,j]*model.soc_param[j] == model.time_soc[0]
model.soc_con0 = Constraint(model.option, rule=soc_con0_rule)
```